# PPTP VPN router (TP-Link TL-R600VPN) does not route to LAN addresses

Tags: router, vpn, pptp

I have been able to connect to my VPN router (TP-Link TL-R600VPN) via PPTP but the only internal/LAN address I can get to is the router (192.168.1.1). I can get to external sites (e.g. google.com) but I can't get to my web server, 192.168.1.142. I'm guessing I need to add a route to the IP table, but I'm not sure what it would be.

The PPTP server provides addresses from 192.168.1.200 to 192.168.1.215. The instructions say to avoid overlapping with the DHCP address space (192.168.1.2-192.168.1.139) and I'm avoiding the address space I'm using for reserved IP addresses (192.168.1.140-192.168.1.199).

What am I missing?

**PPTP Server Settings:**

[image]

**System Routing Table:**

[image]

Comment: @TwoForceMember has the same problem, and may have another example.